# R view categorical fields in dataframe as a tree

Tags: r

Lets say I have a data frame with one column (named "Type") with 3 levels. Then within each Type, there are multiple subtypes. I would like to view this data as a tree, displaying only the name of fields and no. of rows matching that categorization. I don't have a huge dataset (say 1000 rows) but would like to see the frequency distribution at various levels.

```
          ------------------------
          A            B         C        (Type)
         (75)        (50)       (25)
          |            |         |
     A1   A2  A3   B1 B2 B3    ....      (SubType). 
   (10)  (15) (50) ...
```

What could make it interesting if there's a third field (say Priority) which spans across all the subtypes.

```
          ------------------------
          A            B         C        (Type)
         (75)        (50)       (25)
          |            |         |
     A1   A2  A3   B1 B2 B3    ....      (SubType). 
   (10)  (15) (50) ...
           \  / \      / \  / 
          High  medium    low             (priority)
```

I am not sure how to get started. Any hints will be helpful. I have made frequency distn. plots using ggplot like this

```
ggplot(DATA, aes(Type, fill = SubType)) + geom_bar(stat = 'bin', alpha = 1)
```

but any more levels below will make it hard to visualize. So I thought a tree structure might be better.

Thanks

Comment: Your suggested data description, where the Priority feature is really a cross-classification with the subtype, suggests you display with contingency tables rather than a tree. Try `with( DATA, table(subtype, priority, Type))`. It's also possible to use `addmargins` or `margin.table`

Comment: @BondedDust Thanks I am looking into that. But perhaps I can continue with tree and have priority repeated across in level 3.